# "comparison between a new and a standard method(s)"

Tags: singular-vs-plural, ellipsis

I want to express "comparison between a new method and a standard method" in the title of my article. But I don't know which one is correct and why.

A. comparison between a new and a standard method

B. comparison between a new and a standard methods

Answer (score 1):

If you fill in the elided first occurrence of *method*, you get

A. comparison between a new method and a standard method
and
B. *comparison between a new method and a standard methods

A is correct, but B sounds wrong because the article *a* doesn't work with plural *methods*.

You could also say either of these:

*comparison between new and standard methods*

*comparison between a new method and a/the standard one.*

Comment: Is this expression "comparison between a new and a standard method" correct?

Comment: It's grammatical.Whether it fits the context depends on the context. (If there are more than one standard methods, and the comparison is to just one if them, it fits.)